# ajax with django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

can i add the ajax code with django?
i have created a simple registraion form that have 5 fields . i wish to disply the each fields in different pages but in a single window . it means  by using next button 5 pages want to disply in a single window. same time all content of each page i want add to my database. is this possible in django with ajax..

my codes are as follows  :

```
      #view 

        from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
        from registration.models import UserDetails
        from forms import UserForm
        from django import forms
        from django.template import RequestContext
        from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

        def user_details(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = UserForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()


            else:
                form = UserForm()        
            return render_to_response("career.html", {"form": form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))



#form 

     from django import forms
     from registration.models import UserDetails

     class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        pass

        class Meta:
            model = UserDetails



#model 

        from django.db import models

        class UserDetails(models.Model):
            fname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
            lname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
            email = models.EmailField()
            address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
            def __unicode__(self):
                return self.fname
                return self.lname
                return self.email
                return self.address
                return self.country



 #url

        from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

        from django.contrib import admin
        admin.autodiscover()

        urlpatterns = patterns('',
            # Examples:
             url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.user_details', name='user_details'),

            url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        )



 # template 

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
           <input type="submit" ....>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [forms and ajax in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063651/forms-and-ajax-in-django)

Comment: Please do not post multiple versions of the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Whay have you tried for ajax call?

Server just serve some result to client then it is up to your client code:

- either it is post back that you refresh page
- or iframe, you refresh a frame in parent doc
- or html tag like tag that you inject by $(targetElement).html($someResultFromServer)

In most case server does not even care what and how it looks like client(rich or thin),
Thats you javascript, query and css codes which to works on behalf of client. Vice versa, in most case client does not even care  what is and how it looks like it is server: Loosely coupled

For ajax calls you can follow this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

As Martin Thurau stated your question is very hard to understand. Regardless I think that what you are asking for is a stepped form.

Best you take a look at [Django's Form Wizard here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)