# forms and ajax in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ajax with django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063241/ajax-with-django-forms)

can i add the ajax code with django ? i have created a simple registraion form that have 5 fields . i wish to disply the each fields in different pages but in a single window . it means by using next button 5 pages want to disply in a single window. same time all content of each page i want add to my database. is this possible in django with ajax..

my codes are as follows :

```
#model 

            from django.db import models

            class UserDetails(models.Model):
                fname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
                lname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
                email = models.EmailField()
                address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
                country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
                def __unicode__(self):
                    return self.fname
                    return self.lname
                    return self.email
                    return self.address
                    return self.country

 #form 

         from django import forms
         from registration.models import UserDetails

         class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
            pass

            class Meta:
                model = UserDetails


 #view 

            from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
            from registration.models import UserDetails
            from forms import UserForm
            from django import forms
            from django.template import RequestContext
            from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

            def user_details(request):
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = UserForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()

                else:
                    form = UserForm()        
                return render_to_response("career.html", {"form": form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))



  #url

            from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

            from django.contrib import admin
            admin.autodiscover()

            urlpatterns = patterns('',

                 url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.user_details', name='user_details'),

                url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
            )




  # template 

            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
               <input type="submit" ....>
            </form>
```